# Access build number from Azure Devops to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that is hosted on an Azure App service.

I am getting that build number inside YAML file like this:

```
variables:
  buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # Define a variable to hold the build number

steps:
- script: echo "Setting BUILD_NUMBER environment variable to $(buildNumber)"
  displayName: 'Set BUILD_NUMBER'

- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_NUMBER]$(buildNumber)"
  displayName: 'Set BUILD_NUMBER environment variable'
```

I can see that build number in the log when it builds.

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I have a method to read that value

```
 string buildNumber = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER") ?? "not available";
```

However, `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER")` is always null and `BUILD_NUMBER` is not found.

Question is, how do I associate `BUILD_NUMBER` inside the `.yaml` file with the API method, so that this build number can be retrieved in the API?

Am I missing a step here? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you do building of your API in cloud agent or - and where your Web API is deployed ?

Comment: API is hosted in azure app service, vmimage is used inside yaml.

Comment: so you are updating the env vars in vmimage and expect to see them in app service .. i think those are two different environments. vmimage is env only for to build/test etc right ? or am I missign something ?

Comment: The Yaml file builds the project and publishes the artifacts, while doing so, the build number is captured in a variable in the YAML pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue could be that setting the environment variable would only work if you started your console application via dotnet run.

Refer to this doc: [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2)

> When the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable is set globally, it takes effect for dotnet run in any command window opened after the value is set.

You can run the **dotnet run** command in Azure Pipeline and check if the environment variable can pass to application successfully.

Here is my test sample:

Add the code to .cs file:

```
string buildNumber = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER");
Console.WriteLine(buildNumber);
```

Run dotnet Run in Azure Pipeline:

```
variables:
  buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)' # Define a variable to hold the build number

steps:
- script: echo "Setting BUILD_NUMBER environment variable to $(buildNumber)"
  displayName: 'Set BUILD_NUMBER'

- script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_NUMBER]$(buildNumber)"
  displayName: 'Set BUILD_NUMBER environment variable'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'run'
    projects: 'SampleWebApiAspNetCore/SampleWebApiAspNetCore.csproj'
```

[image]

If you want to let it work when deploying to Azure Web App, you can set the variable to **appsettings** of Azure Web App in the Azure App Service Deploy task.

For example:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: AA'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    WebAppName: appname
    AppSettings: '-BUILD_NUMBER $(BUILD_NUMBER)'
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Azure App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#azure-app-service)

Comment: Thanks, i used inside the YAML file AppSettings: '-BUILD_NUMBER $(BUILD_NUMBER)' doesn't replace with actual build number, instead with this direct $(BUILD_NUMBER) value. Any thoughts?

I even tried AppSettings: 'BUILD_NUMBER=$(Build.BuildNumber)' got parameter name can't be empty error, do you know what is the right syntax for appsettings inside YAML?

Comment: Replacing this line AppSettings: '-BUILD_NUMBER $(BUILD_NUMBER)' with this
AppSettings: '-BUILD_NUMBER $(Build.Build_Number)' did the trick, able to view the build number.

Another step that needs to happen is inside appservice, under configuration, create 1 application setting for Build_Number and leave its value empty.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 may I know if it can work as expected after setting the app settings value in app service?

Comment: Step 1: Create a configuration - new app setting - Build_Number in the app service of the  api. 
Step 2: In the YAML file enter the AppSettings value as mentioned in the above comment
AppSettings: '-BUILD_NUMBER $(Build.Build_Number)' 

Then it yields the actual result, this is what worked for me.